# Android Github action with Gradle Managed Device

Tags: android, github-actions, android-espresso, gradle-managed-device

I try to make a CI test with [Gradle Managed Device](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/gradle-managed-devices) and Github action. I made several [attempts](https://github.com/hannesa2/testing-samples/pulls), but I mostly run into

```
 Execution failed for task ':app:nexusOneApi30Setup'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.ManagedDeviceSetupTask$ManagedDeviceSetupRunnable
   > java.lang.IllegalStateException: Gradle was not able to complete device setup for: dev30_aosp_atd_x86_Nexus_One
     This could be due to having insufficient resources to provision the number of
     devices requested. Try running the test again and request fewer devices or
     fewer shards.
```

As source I use https://github.com/android/testing-samples/tree/main/ui/espresso/ScreenshotSample in my [fork](https://github.com/hannesa2/testing-samples/pull/1) which works local properly

Answer (score 0):

Are you sharding?  If yes, try fewer shards.  Or just 1.

Also, it could be a license issue that needs to be accepted.  Try:

```
$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager  --licenses
```